# Please explain the Field Element Aggregation attribute

Tags: site-column, field-definition

I am not quite understanding the use of the Field Element attribute 'Aggregation'. The Field Element : Defines the internal data types used in the list infrastructure of a SharePoint Web site.

The 'Aggregation' attribute :
Aggregation = "sum" | "count" | "average" | "min" | "max" | "merge" | "plaintext" | "first" | "last"

How I have used it :

```
Field ID="{6C330A88-BAFA-4E10-BB94-6ACA4DBF090D}" Name="NPC_BudgFTE" Description="The budgeted fte for employee" DisplayName="Budgeted FTE" EnableLookup="TRUE" Group="NPCA" Type="Integer" Required="FALSE" Aggregation="Sum"
```

I am trying to understand exactly what this attribute does. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Optional Text. Used in an aggregate field on an XML form to specify the function to apply to a collection of values or elements returned by an XPath expression. If you use the Node attribute to specify an XPath expression that returns a collection of values, you can also include an Aggregation attribute that specifies the action to take on the value set that is returned. This action can be either an aggregation function or an indication of the particular element within the collection.
Possible values include the following:
sum   Add the values.
count   Count the number of values.
average   Find the average of the values.
min   Find the minimum value.
max   Find the maximum value.
merge   Merge the values.
plaintext   Converts node text content into plain text.
first   Apply property promotion and demotion to the first element in the collection.
last   Apply property promotion and demotion to the last element in the collection.
For more information about how the Node, PIAttribute, PITarget, PrimaryPIAttribute, and PrimaryPITarget attributes are used for property promotion and demotion in XML documents, see Using Content Types to Specify XML Document Properties.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437580.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I had read that previously but was looking for a real world example of how one would implement and use this? Thanks again!